# Comparing 2 dates in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make a trial system in Node.js. In my mongoose schema, I put a Date.now which returns `2022-07-31T21:59:27.324+00:00`

Then, using Date.now, how would I see if the current date is X days past the saved date?

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the dates to get the difference in milliseconds

```
let date1 = new Date("2022-07-31T21:59:27.324+00:00")
let date2 = new Date("2022-08-26T21:59:27.324+00:00")
let differenceInDays = (date2 - date1)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Comment: Which number represents the days? 24 for 24 hours?

Comment: yep. 1000 converts milliseconds to seconds, 60 converts seconds to minutes, 60 converts minutes to hours, and 24 converts hours to days

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the difference in whole days (e.g., the number of date boundaries crossed between the two points in time), or do you want the number of 24 hour periods passed?

To get the first, the easiest way would be to simply install a modern date/time package like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon):

```bash
npm install luxon
```

Then it's a simple matter of asking it:

```
var end   = DateTime.fromISO('2017-03-13');
var start = DateTime.fromISO('2017-02-13');

var diffInMonths = end.diff(start, 'days');
diffInDays.toObject(); //=> { days: 13 }
```

To get the latter, just do a little arithmetic:

- 1 day is 24 hours;
- 1 hour is 60 minutes;
- 1 minute is 60 seconds;
- 1 second is 1000 milliseconds

Hence 1 day is 86,400,000 milliseconds (24 * 60 * 60 * 60).

```
const DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const diffInMilliseconds = dt1 - dt2 ;
const diffInDays = diffInMilliseconds / DAY ;
```

that will give you fractional days: use `Math.round()`, `Math.floor()`, or `Math.ceil()` as appropriate to get rid of the fractional part.j

You can get the former via arithmetic, too, it's just a little more complicated:

```
function dateDiffInCalendarDays( dtFrom, dtThru ) {
  // clone the arguments, and allow numeric timestamps
  const from = new Date(dtFrom) ;
  const thru = new Date(dtThru) ;
  
  // set the time components to midnight/start-of-day
  from.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  thru.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  const deltaInWholeDays = thru - from;

  return deltaInWholeDays;
}
```